# Drawing circular gradient shade outlining shape

Tags: android, drawing, drawable, shapes, shadowing

So, I have a white circular shape described in the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/color_white"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/color_white" />
    <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

I've been trying to produce an outlining like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/masbc.png), with a gradient (notice that there is a shadow with gradient surrounding it):

I've tried using a layer-list, but it didn't work, because one image would be on top of the other and the background image would not appear.
My idea would be to have the white circular shape and the shadow in the background, slightly bigger than the white one, producing the outlining.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this [drawable](https://gist.github.com/MrOnyszko/4a50ed5aa6d58784e9ff8ec80f497809) and it looks like

[image]